# How to remove not enclosed dirty text before first tag

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I have a dirty HTML which looks something like this

Example 1:

```
<div>

  somedirtytexthere.

  <h1>header 1</h1>
  <p>ok this text is cool</p>
</div>
```

Example 2:

```
<div>

  somedirtytexthere.

  <h1>header 1</h1>
  <p>ok this text is cool</p>
       but this text is ALSO cool
</div>
```

I want to remove every (not enclosed) text element in front of the first child tag of `div` with jQuery.

Comment: @CIRCLE: That will clear it entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("div")
    .contents()
    .filter(function () {
        return this.nodeType === 3;
    }).first().remove();
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/zpUwu/1/)

Comment: ok this works and applies filter to all div content. But I do not want to loose not enclosed text after the header 1 occured. I've edited my example.

Comment: @therealmarv - I've updated my answer. Now it will select the first text node and remove that. Demo is updated too.